# Zend_Mail: how to get attachment ID?

Tags: image, inline, attachment, zend-mail

I am using Zend to create emails.
Now I will place an inline image in the HTML Part of the mail.
So I am attaching the image with:

```
$imageContent = file_get_contents(APPLICATION_PATH.'../html/static/img/image.jpg');
$image = $mail->createAttachment($imageContent,
    'image/jpeg',
    Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE,
    Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
    'image.png');
$imageHeaders = $image->getHeaders();
```

The last command is for getting the headers, where the part id is not set.
But for linking the image in the mail I need the attachment id, so how can you get it?

Comment: or is there a posiibility to set the id manulally?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it yourself, see the manual: [36.3. Zend Mime Part](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mime.part.html), for example:

```
$this->id = md5($file);
```