# php library for embedding images in email

Tags: php, email, class

Which php library makes it easy to embed images into an email.

Comment: This thread seems like a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536838/php-attaching-an-image-to-an-email Although it wasn't asking for a library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use http://swiftmailer.org/ and it's very good and easy to use if you send less emails eta less than 100 K per hour for bulk of emails, in that case it could be memory consuming. Generally it is good tool.

Answer (score 2):

[Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.attachments.html) seems pretty easy.  From the example code:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
// build message...
$mail->createAttachment($myImage,
                        'image/gif',
                        Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE,
                        Zend_Mime::ENCODING_8BIT);
```

If you want to reference the image in the HTML part of the e-mail, this [SO thread may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147097/zendmail-how-to-get-attachment-id).

Answer (score 1):

I did found [htmlMimeMail5](http://www.phpguru.org/downloads/html.mime.mail/htmlMimeMail5/) which is quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the PEAR packages related to this (Mail/Mime).

Here is the documentation:
http://pear.activeventure.com/package/package.mail.mail-mime.addhtmlimage.html

Here is a sample:
http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/need-an-example-for-embedding-image-using-pear-mail-mime-134461.html?p=615813